# Child Process is failing using Popen

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a program named xselect to run using the Popen construct in python. If I run xselect from the terminal manually by typing in the commands by hand, It runs all the way through. However, when done from the python script, it freezes at a certain command and will not continue. When I check the log file, all of the output is captured, but none of the error messages are captured.

I'm thinking that Popen may not know what to do with the errors from the output of xselect, and its causing xselect to freeze. To counter this, I tried to add a timeout so that it kills xselect after 5 seconds, but this hasn't worked either.

Can anyone help me get this running?

```
with subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True) as proc:


    proc.wait(timeout=5)
    out = proc.stdout.read()
    if TimeoutExpired:
        proc.kill()
```

Answer (score 0):

See the warning for `proc.wait()` here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait. Basically, you should either be using `proc.communicate()`, or should be reading from `proc.stdout` instead of waiting.